# How to assign string pointer value to elements of a vector using loops in C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```
int main()
{
    string word = word;
    string word1;
    string word2;
    string word3;
    string word4;
    string word5;
    string *pointer = &word;
    string words[5] = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5 };
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        word[i] = *pointer;
        cout << word[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I assigned the "location memory" of the string word to the pointer.  I want to use the loop to assign its value to all the elements in the array named "words".  However, it keep getting the errors: 
(Error  1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'  e:\day 1\day 1\testing_concatenating and assigning.cpp  32  1   Day 1)
and 
(   2   IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "char" exists   e:\Day 1\Day 1\testing_concatenating and assigning.cpp  32  13  Day 1)

Comment: typo: `word[i]` -> `words[i]`

Comment: Better use a `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::array<std::string,5>` instead.

Comment: Are you sure `word1` through `word5` are doing anything?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::vector` really doesn't add much here (except space requirements), possibly `std::array` but possibly it makes sense to understand plain old arrays when starting

Comment: @Aniekan Umoren The error messages do not correspond to the shown code that contains a few typos. Show the actual code.

Comment: I am amused that `string word = word;` doesn't generate a warning. Sure, strings aren't uninitialized in the way `int x = x;` would be, but assigning to self during initialization's pretty damn unusual and worth a, "Yo! You really ought to take a look at this."

Answer (score 2):

```
word[i] = *pointer;
```

- `word` is a `string`. `word[i]` is a `char`.
- `pointer` is a `string*`. `*pointer` is a `string`.

You're trying to assign `string` to `char`. You probably meant `words[i]` instead of `word[i]`.

To avoid typos leading to compilable code, try naming your variables more descriptively. *Especially avoid names that differ only in one letter.*

Comment: I up-voted, but I think you were down-voted because it technically doesn't answer the OP question.

Comment: @EvanCarslake: In what sense does this not answer the question?

Comment: Technically there's no question in OP's post. And if there is one, the question should be closed as "unclear what you're asking", since that question is certainly not easy to find/understand.

Answer (score 2):

`word` is a `string`. A `string` is composed of `char`s. You cannot store a `string` in a `string`. You need to store a `char` in a string. For example

```
word[0] = 'a'
```

is legal, while

```
word[0] = some_other_string
```

is not.

Also you cannot initialize a variable with its own value as you did in line 1 of `main()`

Answer (score 1):

Assign variable word with some string. Further you try to use a variable as an array.

```
word[i] = *pointer;
```

Look carefully that the variable word is a string object while you use it as an array which is wrong!
Here is ideone example that I have created from your code:
[Example](http://ideone.com/1e1qks)

Answer (score 0):

You have a string variable called `word` and an array called `words`. In your loop, you access `word[i]` (the string variable) instead of `words[i]` (the array).

Answer (score 0):

If to provide that your code would compile then it can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word = "word";
    string word1 /*= some initializer */;
    string word2 /*= some initializer */;
    string word3 /*= some initializer */;
    string word4 /*= some initializer */;
    string word5 /*= some initializer */;
    string *pointer = &word;
    string words[5] = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        words[i] = *pointer;
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

However there is no great sense to define a pointer to the object `word`. You could use it itslef. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word = "word";
    string word1 /*= some initializer */;
    string word2 /*= some initializer */;
    string word3 /*= some initializer */;
    string word4 /*= some initializer */;
    string word5 /*= some initializer */;
    string words[5] = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        words[i] = word;
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

You could use the range based for statement. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word = "word";
    string word1 /*= some initializer */;
    string word2 /*= some initializer */;
    string word3 /*= some initializer */;
    string word4 /*= some initializer */;
    string word5 /*= some initializer */;
    string words[5] = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5 };

    for ( string &s : words ) s = word;
}
```

Or you could use standard algorithm `std::fill` declared in header `<algorithm>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word = "word";
    string word1 /*= some initializer */;
    string word2 /*= some initializer */;
    string word3 /*= some initializer */;
    string word4 /*= some initializer */;
    string word5 /*= some initializer */;
    string words[5] = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5 };

    fill( words, words + 5, word );
}
```

If you mean a pointer of type `char *` then the code will look

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *word = "word";
    string word1 /*= some initializer */;
    string word2 /*= some initializer */;
    string word3 /*= some initializer */;
    string word4 /*= some initializer */;
    string word5 /*= some initializer */;
    string words[5] = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        words[i] = word;
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word = "word";
    string word1 /*= some initializer */;
    string word2 /*= some initializer */;
    string word3 /*= some initializer */;
    string word4 /*= some initializer */;
    string word5 /*= some initializer */;
    const char *pointer = word.c_str();
    string words[5] = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        words[i] = pointer;
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Take into account that the valid range of indices for the array words is `[0, 4]So you have to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                ^^^^^`
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through the OP's code and trying to explain what's going on:

```
int main()
{
    string word = word; // this creates a string named word and sets word
                        // to itself. In other words, other than creating
                        // word, it doesn't do anything.
                        // most likely the intent was
                        // string word = "word";
                        // The "" marks contained text as data to be
                        // Interpreted as a string
    string word1; // these create more words set to the default 
    string word2; // empty string that don't do much for reasons explained 
    string word3; // below
    string word4;
    string word5;
    string *pointer = &word; // this is good

    string words[5] = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5 };
    // this created an array of 5 strings and copied the values of word1
    // through word5 into array elements 0 through 4. Since word1 through 5
    // contain the default value, this does nothing more than
    // string words[5];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) // words contains 5 slots, 0 though 4.
                                 // the loop conditions cover 0 through 5
                                 // it will compile but will have undefined
                                 // behaviour (maybe crash, maybe not)
                                 // when words[5] is reached.
                                 // Very likely the intent was
                                 // for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        word[i] = *pointer; // this is most likely a typo.
                            // The odd message about assigning a string to
                            // a character is because you can use [] to
                            // access individual characters in a string
                            // just like you can an array
                            // words[i] = *pointer; 
                            // is probably what was intended
        cout << word[i] << endl; // this is good, but probably not what is 
                                 // intended. It will print out the 
                                 // characters in word one by one.
                                 // as with above, it likely should be 
                                 // cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Corrected and with the chaff removed we get

```
int main1()
{
    string word = "word";
    string *pointer = &word;

    string words[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        words[i] = *pointer;
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A slightly safer approach. We can bind the loop to the number of strings in words by dividing the total size of the words array by the size of a single element. This way it can never run out of bounds. Note I have changed the type of i from int, a signed value, to size_t, an unsigned value perfectly suited to be used as an index.

```
int main2()
{
    string word = "word";
    string *pointer = &word;

    string words[5];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]); i++)
    {
        words[i] = *pointer;
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or we can use the enhanced for loop from C++11

```
int main3()
{
    string word = "word";
    string *pointer = &word;

    string words[5];

    for (string & wordref: words) // note the &. In this case we are using a reference, 
                                  // a restricted pointer, to the strings in words.
                                  // We need the reference or a pointer because 
                                  // otherwise we will be given a copy of the string 
                                  // in words, and the assignment will be to the copy, 
                                  // not to the source string in words.
    {
        wordref = *pointer;
        cout << wordref << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```